Compiling Bootstrap v5.3.3 with Dart Sass results in deprecation warnings
It seems that the Bootstrap team has switched from "Node.js" to "Dart Sass" for its compilation. But I get a lot of deprecation warnings using Dart Sass.
When compiling the Bootstrap (.scss) source files using from Dart Sass there are many deprecation warnings (import, color,...).
How do I fix this without changing the source files? The --quiet-deps flag also does not silence the warnings (there is a specific one for @import warnings: --silence-deprecation=import) like color, etc...
